Two questions on feasible cones of closures of open connected domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at a boundary point
Let $U$ be an open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ The feasible cone at a boundary point $x\in \partial{U}$ is defined by:
$$F_x(\bar{U}):=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists t_0 > 0 \text{ so that }  x + tv \in \bar{U} \forall t \in (0, t_0)\}.$$
I've two questions on this feasible cone.
1) One possible (counter) example: When we examine the complement of $F_x(\bar{U}),$ I understand  that it's the set of points $v\in  \mathbb{R}^n$ so that there doesn't exists a $t_0>0$ so that $x+tv \in \bar{U}, \forall 0 < t < t_0.$ But the complement still can contain the following set of vectors:
$$G_x(\bar{U}):=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists \{t_n\}_{n\ge 1} \to 0, t_n >0 \text{ so that }x + t_nv \in \bar{U}\}.$$
In other words, the complement of the feasible cone can still contain vectors/directions so that the line in that direction can pass through both $\bar{U}$ and its complement infinitely many times. For example, if we take $U:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:y >  sin(1/x), x \in (0, \infty) \}, F_0(\bar{U})$ is the vertical $Y$-axis (because the limit points of the graph of $sin(1/x)$ is every point in the vertical direction from $-1$ to $+1.$  But here $G_0(\bar{U})$ is the right half plane. So here $F_0(\bar{U})$ is a proper sub set of $G_0(\bar{U}).$
Is the above correct?
2) Condition to guarantee equality of $F$ and $G$ above:  Question 1) above brings me to the related question: what condition(s) on $U$ can we put on $U$ to conclude that:
$$F_x(\bar{U})=  G_x(\bar{U}),$$
i.e. what condition(s) on $U$, or perhaps on its boundary, guarantee(s) that as long as a small scale multiple of a direction/vector v is in $\bar{U},$ a small segment in that direction starting at $x$ lies entirely in $\bar{U}?$
I can imagine that $U$ being convex will prevent the infinite wiggling of the boundary as in the example in 1), but it seems it's not necessary, here's an example (sorry for the bad drawing!)

Above $U$ is the blue region, and $F_x(\bar{U})$ is the red region. Note that since the non-convex $U$ has a 'nice' boundary near $x$(it dosn't wiggle infinitely near $x$), the vectors $x+tz$ lying on the line passing through $x$ and $z,z \notin cl(F_x(\bar{U}))$ (cl=closure) has $x+tz \notin \bar{U}$ for all small positive $t.$ And in this case indeed $F_x(\bar{U})=G_x(\bar{U}).$
I'm trying to understand how nice the boundary has to be, i.e. what conditions can we put on $U$ in order to ensure the above $F_x(\bar{U})=G_x(\bar{U}).$?

I think your reasoning under 1 is correct.
Question number 2 is more delicate. Of course, convexity of $U$ is enough. In absence of convexity, there is little hope, I think.
In optimization, one typically studies sets of the form
$$
F = \{ x \mid g(x) \le 0; h(x) = 0\}.
$$
Moreover, for non-convex $F$, one typically considers the so-called tangent cone
$$
T_F(x) = \{ d \in \mathbb R^n \mid \exists \{t_n\} \subset (0,\infty), \{x_n\} \subset F : t_n \searrow 0, (x_n - x)/t_n \to d\}.
$$
This cone has nicer properties than the cone of critical directions. Under so-called constraint qualifications (CQs), this cone can be written in terms of the derivatives $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$.

Thank you for your answer, and mentioning CQ's, I'll look into it. I  my setup, the open set $U$ is a locally a super level set of a continuous function, that's not necessarily differentiable.
About the point of convexity, I understand that the tangent cone in this case is the closure of the cone of feasible directions. But my question is about infinitely many intersections of $\bar{U}$ with the line segment $t\mapsto x+tz, 0\le t \le 1,$ where $z\notin \bar{U}.$ Intuitively (I'll explain below) this seems to imply (contd.)

(contd.) that infinitely many intersections of $\partial{U}$ with the segment $t\mapsto x+tz, 0\le t \le 1.$ "Intuitively" is rigorous if we can prove
But if we assume the above to be true, it seems prevention of "infinite wiggling" near the boundary point $x$ suffices to guarantee that $F_x(\bar{U})=G_x(\bar{U}).$ Not sure if we need convexity for this, as U the image in OP is nonconvex.
